# 301. htaccess redirect not working due to regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I have a little bit of trouble with a redirect

I'd like to redirect every incoming traffic from

http://domain.com/?friends=7 to 
http://domain.com/win

I am using this rule, but it does not seem to work.

```
RewriteRule ^\?friends\=7$ /win [R=301]
```

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained

Answer (score 1):

You can't catch a query string with a `RewriteRule` you need to use a `RewriteCond` for this task:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^friends=7$
RewriteRule ^$ /win? [L,R=301]
```

You can test your `RewriteRule` using [this tool](http://htaccess.mwl.be/)